# different between bindec($value) and hexdec(bin2hex($value)) PHP

Tags: php, type-conversion

I'have a `$value` like that `var_dump(bin2hex($value))` output = `'015180'`

I want the convert this value to decimal. So I know my `$value` is binary, I write those codes:

```
var_dump(bindec($value));// 0
var_dump(hexdec(bin2hex($value)));//86400
```

Result is  `86400` but why don't the first one returns me `0`. what is the different between two of them. Or Am I missing something ?

Comment: Can you please show us the original value of `$value`? Make a copy/paste example if your issue.

Comment: var_dump($value) output is 'Q�'

Answer (score 1):

I'm only quoting one of comments in `bin2hex` documentation:

> bin2hex function is for converting binary data into a hexadecimal string representation.  This function is not for converting strings representing binary digits into hexadecimal.If you want that functionality, you can simply do this:

```
<?php
$binary = "11111001";
$hex = dechex(bindec($binary));
echo $hex;
?>
```

> This would output "f9".  Just remember that there is a very big difference between binary data and a string representation of binary.

Author: tehjosh

Comment: var_dump($value) output is 'Q�'  how can i get 86400 with one type convertion

Comment: `bin2hex` takes string as param. Probably Your binary data is evaluated to some value  which produces 86400 from `hexdec`.

Comment: Have You any proof?

Comment: Trying and writing output :D i need to write bin2hex before hexdec